# How do I acquire SDKs to build target pre-8.0 iOS?

Tags: xcode, ios

I have installed XCode 6 and it came with the iOS 8 SDK but i need to test on devices still running 7.1 and cannot figure out how to get the iOS 7 SDK now without downloading an older version of XCode than I already have installed. Where can I find the previous SDKs and can I install them in my newer version of XCode?

Answer (score 17):

You don't need previous SDK to build for iOS7. Change *Deployment Target* in Xcode.

Here are differences between Deployment Target and Base SDK: http://www.raywenderlich.com/42591/supporting-multiple-ios-versions-and-devices

> Base SDK refers to the newest version of iOS that is capable of running your app. To check which base SDK you are building your app against, simply open your project file in Xcode and check the setting under Build Settings -> Architecture(...)
>
> Deployment Target refers to the oldest version of iOS that is capable of running your project. To change your deployment target, open up your project file in Xcode and check the setting under Build Settings -> Deployment(...)

Base SDK can be changed here:
[image: Base SDK]

Deployment target can be changed here:
[image: Deployment target]

Check [this answer to add earlier devices support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39449405/525578).

Comment: In XCode 6 I can't find *any* menu item labeled "Build Settings". This is what is tripping me up: all the screenshots and help I find are for older XCode versions.

Comment: I've added screenshots to my post.

Comment: Xcode 8 has no 7.0 deployment target

Comment: @Sergei that's correct, but it's hard to blame Apple, iOS7 i quite old... In that case you can download older Xcode from developer.apple.com

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I just typed it to the field and it works!